# Format GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, format

I have a gridview with autogenerated columns that I set programmatically I want to format the column width. This is my code for my gridview in code behind...

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    Dim budgetTable As New DataTable("Budgets")

    budgetTable.Columns.Add("Approval Date", GetType(Date))
    budgetTable.Columns.Add("Total Amount", GetType(String))
    budgetTable.Columns.Add("Comments", GetType(String))
    budgetTable.Columns.Add("Initials", GetType(String))

    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To 0
            Dim tableRow As DataRow = budgetTable.NewRow()
            tableRow("Approval Date") = Date.Today
            tableRow("Total Amount") = ""
            tableRow("Comments") = ""
            tableRow("Initials") = ""
            budgetTable.Rows.Add (tableRow)
        Next
        Session("BudgetsTable") = budgetTable
        BindData()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End If
```

And this is the gridview on the html side:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvOLIAdj" runat="server" CssClass="td8" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" PageSize="2" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />

    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField EditText="Add" ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>

    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What has this to do with VBA?

Comment: duplicate?-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546299/gridview-column-width-altering

Comment: change to `AutoGenerateColumns='False'` and specify columns and set `item-width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-- EDIT --**

(removed old contents after reading comments from OP, since that won't help)

Try using the RowDataBound event to set the widths (or any other properties).

UNTESTED Code:

```
Protected Sub gvOLIAdj_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvOLIAdj.RowDataBound
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Header) Then
        e.Row.Cells(0).Width = 100  '100 pixels
        e.Row.Cells(1).Width = 50
        e.Row.Cells(2).Width = 200
        e.Row.Cells(3).Width = 150
    End If
End Sub
```

If the above doesn't work, try setting it for `e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow`.

Comment: @rt2800 and Predeep Kumar... I tried both those options I saw the post first... I keep getting an error message "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index" as soon as I hit my first dynamically created column?

Comment: ok.. my bad. I just forgot that you are using dynamically generated columns. The columns collection is not updated for the dynamically generated columns (for some reason or the other, known only to the control creators). So the upper-bound remains 0. And as a result you can't address them by column numbers.

Comment: Updated the code above. Give it a try and see if it is of any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a style sheet to accomplish it:

```
.td8 td:nth-child(3) {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Assumes you want the third column to be 100px. This is a CSS3 option, so it will only work with the newer browsers.

**Edit:**
Reading the comment you made to @Pradeep Kumar, you may be applying the width to the column too soon. Try making those changes in the `Page_PreRender` event after the GridView has been bound and created. Keep in mind, the columns in the GridView do not exist until **after** the RowItemCreated events have completed entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the help from everyone but nothing is working... I'm about to give up. lol

Comment: @developthestars: The one piece of code you didn't include in your sample is where you're actually attempting to set the width. Perhaps if you shared how you're even attempting to do that we could be more helpful.